# DWM doesnt log me out, instead just closes

Tags: xorg, dwm

I had DWM working just fine for a while now and (I don't remember making any changes outside of xinitrc prior to this) now it no longer logs me out when I press the keybind (killclient). And by log me out I just mean it sent me back to the tty1 shell and from there I could type startx to restart the xorg server with my xinitrc.

Now it just closes DWM, so at that point I either restart manually by pressing my power button or I just type reboot into ST if I had that open.

Comment: How do you start dwm from xinitrc? What else do you start from there?

Comment: Heres my xinitrc https://pastebin.com/raw/ML184d0j and i should mention before my xinitrc was just "exec dwm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are "logged out" not when your window manager exits, but **when your xinitrc script ends.** In simple cases, the script ends when the last non-background (non-&) command invoked by that script exits – which in your script is *not dwm anymore;* you actually have `slstatus` as the last waited-for command, while your `dwm` is being run detached "in background" with `&` for some reason.

Reorder it to:

```
slstatus &
dwm
```

*(`exec dwm` is optional)*

---

Typically, when you have `exec dwm` at the very end of the script, dwm *replaces* the script, so "when xinitrc exits" now becomes "when dwm exits". This would still work without 'exec', as the script would still *wait* for the invoked command to exit (the 'exec' really has only minimal advantages here).

However, running something in background with a `&` stops that from happening – you're specifically asking the script to *not* wait for 'dwm' to exit, and to just continue with the next command (which is slstatus).

The `&` operator also nullifies the `exec` (because "in background" means spawning a separate process, which is completely opposite to what "exec" does), so the `exec dwm &` – which is equivalent to just `dwm &` – no longer defines the lifetime of the script.

Comment: That worked, thanks.